# how do i merge data in integromat from a json webhook to display in google sheets

Tags: make.com

Hi all I am trying to work with integrate after getting data from a JSON webhook, it is coming in like below and the {"0":{ are creat issues are is it making them into blocks and I cat run them into google sheets right, can someone please help me out

[image]

Comment: i am not asking anyone to write software for free I already have it done I am just asking advise

Answer (score 0):

You can put this output into JSON parser module in INtegromat. That is the next step (the pink module). For there you will generate JSON structure and able to access elements one by one.

Also Iterator module can be used, but not necessarily. Depending on what is required next. Contact me if you need help.